# Django: 'python manage.py syncdb' does not create my schema tables

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, web

Here is my models.py

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.db import models

class P(models.Model):
    n = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class I(models.Model):
    t = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    p = models.ForeignKey(P)
```

Here is command line:

```
rm db.sqlite3 
$ python manage.py syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK

You have installed Django's auth system, and don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): no
```

It pretends it has done everything but I do not see tables in DB, neither my code does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your app is listed in the [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) in the project settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'your_app',
)
```

Comment: You are welcome, your progress for the past year is fantastic. Really glad to have you here on SO.